# Where will file be saved in heroku for node.js app?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am create a file from a buffer and saving it to my heroku virtual machine:

```
var wstream = fs.createWriteStream( name + '.wav');
wstream.write(buffer)

wstream.end()
```

I need to send that file to google cloud storage using its absolute path: Do you know what the path will be?

```
path = '?'
```

Comment: Why not stream directly to Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: The file needs to be processed in my node. js app first

Comment: Sure, but why write the file instead of processing the stream and then outputting to GCS?

Comment: You can use something like [this](https://github.com/rauschma/stringio) to make it easy.

Comment: I already have everything working, I just need to do it this way. So do you know the absolute path to the file?

Comment: `__dirname` is the current directory, so if `name` doesn't have a directory separator, use `__dirname + name + '.wav'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application root on Heroku should be `/app`. So if you have a file named `foo.txt` in the root of your repo, it would be `/app/foo.txt`. You can confirm this by opening up a console (e.g. `heroku run bash`) and running `pwd`.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed.